# Azure VM with multiple custom domains

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-dns

I am currently running a multi-tennant website in Azure under a web app.
I more than happy with the performance and scalablity options.

But...

I'm rapidly approaching the 500 custom domains limit. So need a new option.

I'm assuming this limit isn't applicable with an Azure VM?

Is it just a case of adding any new custom domains to IIS and the windows Host file?

Can this work be scripted via powershell?

How scalable are VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. no, for azure vm you can have as many custom domain, because they are just CNAME records
2. not sure why you would need hosts file, that is certainly one way to do it, but not for front facing apps. you would need your hosts file changes for anybody accessing the site.
3. this is more of a question to your DNS provider, but they usually have some sort of API you can talk to >> so you can automate this.
4. well, you can achieve scalability, but its not going to be straight forward (compared to App Services). You would need either vms with availability set or vmss (virtual machine scale set). You would also need a process to update your code on them  and probably several other things (like how to install certificates etc).

Comment: Thanks, so it would be a case of setting up the custom domain name in IIS AND as long as the CNAME record on the domain name is configured to point at the websites IP it should be fine?

Comment: yeah, if you want scalability you'd need to point to load balancer\application gateway ip address though.